# How to use DataTemplateSelector with a DataGridBoundColumn?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate, datatemplateselector

I followed the simple method described [here](http://www.paulstovell.com/dynamic-datagrid) and have a DataGrid with dynamically generated columns which allows DataTemplates to be used and bound dynamically.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < testDataGridSourceList.DataList[0].Count; i++)
        {
            var binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", i));
            CustomBoundColumn customBoundColumn = new CustomBoundColumn();
            customBoundColumn.Header = "Col" + i;
            customBoundColumn.Binding = binding;
            customBoundColumn.TemplateName = "CustomTemplate";
            TestControlDataGrid.TestDataGrid.Columns.Add(customBoundColumn);
        }
```

Each column is of type CustomBoundColumn which derives from DataGridBoundColumn

```
public class CustomBoundColumn : DataGridBoundColumn
{
    public string TemplateName { get; set; }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var binding = new Binding(((Binding)Binding).Path.Path);
        binding.Source = dataItem;

        var content = new ContentControl();
        content.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)cell.FindResource(TemplateName);
        content.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, binding);
        return content;
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        return GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
    }
}
```

I would now like to use a DataTemplateSelector to allow each row to use a different DataTemplate instead of just using the "CustomTemplate" shown in the first snippet. How can I do this?

Comment: A different DataTemplate depending on what?

Comment: Depending on the Type of data being shown on that row (I am populating with a list of base classes, but each row may actually be a different derived class with a few extra properties that I would like to make use of in the DataTemplate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I replaced

```
content.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)cell.FindResource(TemplateName);
```

with

```
content.ContentTemplateSelector = (DataTemplateSelector)cell.FindResource("templateSelector");
```

where 'templateSelector' is the key of a DataTemplateSelector declared as a Static Resource in the XAML code. This works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the late answer. I believe the solution is quite simple, just place a `ContentPresenter` in your "CustomTemplate" :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomTemplate">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"
                      ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelector}">
    </ContentPresenter>
</DataTemplate>
```

And there you go! You can now use a `DataTemplateSelector`. A good example [here](https://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html).

Comment: I achieved a similar thing without needing to use the ContentPresenter. Same idea though. +1 for the input

Comment: Your link is broken, can you find another example and paste code please?

Answer (score 0):

I made a custom column class that combines the DataGridBoundColumn with the DataGridTemplateColumn.

You can set Binding and Template on that column.

Here's the source:
[gist](https://gist.github.com/owen2/9354215)

Comment: How did you achieve editing capabilities? For me, the app crashes with `Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.` as soon as I start editing.

Comment: Look at CellEditungTemplate